# How does the cation radius affect the rate of increase of the electrical conductivity of a salt in aqueous solution?

Tags: electrochemistry, conductivity

Potassium chloride has a greater ionic radius than sodium chloride. How does this affect the  fall in rate of increase in conductivity as concentration concentrations? I know the following factors affect the plateauing of the curve:

lesser dissociation, the equilibrium is disturbed as a result of lack of water molecules to fully solvate the ions, ionic pair association and the increased visocity of the solution

In my experiment I found that the decraase of the rate of increase was greater for KCl, which I found weird.

Comment: Ionic radius is not the same as the effective hydrated ionic radius. Their orders for Li Na K are mutually reversed.

Comment: It rather affect ion mobility and therefore molar conductivity. Smaller ions have stronger field and therefore thicker effective AVG layer of attached  water molecules bound to it and following its electromigration.

Comment: Molar conductivity is better parameter than conductivity. $\Lambda = \kappa/c$ BTW I was addressing differences between ions, not concentration effect .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116742/discussion-between-poutnik-and-strawhat).

Comment: @Strawhat It would be nice if you could stop vandalizing your own posts.